# I am learning PHP in school and everyone has this one not working

Tags: php

We use MAMP for our servers and html/css/php files. I have double checked everything and im SURE this has no errors really. It ends up with a local host error. which means it won't display my work. Here is my work:

-- main.php --

```
<?php

require 'person.php'

$person = new Person;
$person->name = 'Froggy';
$person->age = '15';

echo $person->sentence();

 ?>
```

---

--- person.php ---

```
<?php
class Person {
  public $name;
  public $age;


  public function sentence() {
  return $this->name . 'is' . '$this->age' . ' years old';
  }
}
?>
```

So this simple code would show me "'Froggy' is '15' years old" but it wont work. Help?

Comment: There are a couple of errors in the above code, mainly the missing semi-colon after the require line. You should definitely try and get access to the PHP error logs for your servers, or you're going to run into a lot more problems like this.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of "it won't work"?

Comment: First of all, check if `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost:8080/` is working, it should display a default website from MAMP. If it does not display the default site, make sure Apache **is** started/running.

Comment: I'm SURE there are no errors. Lol.

Answer (score 4):

Parse error:

Add semi-colon here

```
require 'person.php';
```

Again, change function to:

```
public function sentence() {
 return $this->name . ' is ' . $this->age . ' years old';
}
```

Issue was that `$this->age` was having single quote around it.

Variables inside single quotes are not parsed, it is called variable interpolation.

Variables inside double quotes however, can be parsed.

**Output:**

```
Froggy is 15 years old
```

Comment: The page on localhost does not work

localhost is currently unable to handle the request .

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around `$this->age`:

```
<?php
class Person {
  public $name;
  public $age;


  public function sentence() {
  return $this->name . 'is' . $this->age . ' years old';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the quotes in your output, you can return this in your function:

```
return "'$this->name' is '$this->age' years old";
```